# Why did Gorr still want to kill Thor?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love & Thunder*, Gorr the God Butcher goes on a mission to kill all gods after being betrayed by his own god, thinking that all gods are selfish and don't care about their people.

He then kidnaps Asgards' children to lure Thor into the dark realm to fight him there.

But seeing Thor coming to rescue the children "his people" should be enough for Gorr to know that Thor is a good god and doesn't deserve to die.

Why did Gorr continue on his mission against Thor?

Comment: Just so you know, this could be marked as opinion-based.

Comment: What? Why? Any question would be opinion based if that is the case. This is a question about the movie plot. It could be answered or not.

Comment: Most answers you'd receive would be speculation, as there aren't really many details in the movie plot or script to show what's actually happening in the context. It's more of a plot necessity thing.

Comment: It is ok, we are not discussing science or software development here. It is sci-fi. Not every question has an answer, we won't know till we ask.

Comment: The Necrosword is to Gorr as the Darkhold is to Wanda.

Comment: The children were Asgardians, so gods like him, not followers of Thor as a god. So Gorr may not have considered his behavior to be altruistic. Plus, Gorr wanted to eliminate all gods, so even if he could see goodness in Thor, he could have considered killing him as acceptable.

Answer (score 10):

#### Gorr didn't care about whether or not the Gods were good, he just wanted their complete extermination and he needed the Bifrost from Asgard.

You are correct in saying that Gorr originally wanted to kill all gods due to the injustices committed by his own god. However, this was only an opportunity to obtain the Necrosword which further corrupted him. At that point, he was hell-bent on killing all gods. He made his way to Asgard to kill the gods there (for example his attempted killing of the Lady Sif), but realized that the Bifrost was under the Asgardians' control. The Bifrost was needed to reach Eternity, who would allow Gorr to kill all gods with a wish (think Infinity Gauntlet level instantaneity and destructiveness). When Gorr realized the Asgardians had the Bifrost, he attacked New Asgard on Earth in order to draw them out. Taking the children was simply a means to an end, a way to get Thor (and thus Stormbreaker) to the Shadow Realm for Gorr to use to get to Eternity. Whether or not Gorr saw that the Asgardian gods were good because of their willingness to go get the children is irrelevant; the Necrosword had corrupted him to the point where he was to kill all gods (the purpose of the Necrosword) and he was willing to go about it any way necessary.

**tl;dr Gorr was already corrupted by the Necrosword, and needed to lure Thor to the Shadow Realm to steal the Bifrost from him.**

Comment: This is actually a good answer.

Comment: "Yes, that's what... answer... means"

Comment: Is this a reference to Eitri's line in infinity wars? 

Comment: Yes. Yes it is.